# How to call activity type extension function from view model using data binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I have created a extension function as below:

```
fun <A : Activity> Activity.startNewActivity(activity: Class<A>) {
    Intent(this, activity).also {
        it.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        startActivity(it)
    }
}
```

I want to call this from my ViewModel class but since ViewModel is not an activity is there any way to achieve this?

In my ViewModel class I want to call this extension function inside the below method which is trigger when a button is clicked:

```
 fun onLoginClicked(view: View) {
        // I want to call that startNewActivity function here..
    }
```

What are the possible ways? I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle click actions which depends on its context in `Activity` itself not in `ViewModel`.

If you want to do it in `ViewModel` you need to have access to Activity's reference which you can also get it from `View` or you can just pass it as method argument.

```
fun onLoginClicked(view: View) {
    (view.context as Activity).startNewActivity(MainActivity::class.java)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [livedata](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) for this kind of purposes, communication between viewmodel and view classes.

In your viewmodel:

```
val onLoginClicked = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

       ...

fun onLoginClicked(view: View) {
    onLoginClicked.value = true
}
```

In your related activity:

```
vm.onLoginClicked.observe(this, Observer { startNewActivity(...) })
```